# Troubleshooting Gitea openrc script in Alpine: Forking and logging issues

Tags: alpine-linux, openrc

I am trying to write an init script for `gitea` in alpine. The first code I tried was

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run
command=/usr/bin/gitea

command_args="web"
pidfile=/var/run/git.pid
name="Gitea Daemon"

description="Gitea - Git with a cup of tea"

start() {
  ebegin "Starting Gitea"
  start-stop-daemon --start --exec /usr/bin/gitea \
    --pidfile /var/run/git.pid 
  eend $?
}

stop() {
  ebegin "Stopping Gitea"
  start-stop-daemon --stop --exec /usr/bin/gitea \
    --pidfile /var/run/git.pid
  eend $?
}
```

Gitea does not fork, so when running above code, the service is starting and running but stays in foreground. So I tried to add `--background` option to `start-stop-daemon`. Now it is forking but the service is shown as „crashed“ although it’s running. I can fix this by manually creating a `git.pid` file, otherwise the service is unusable (won’t start nor stop) until I remove `/var/run/openrc/started/git` manually.

When using the code above and calling it in background by

```
rc-service git start &
```

It will start gitea but `rc-status` shows the service as „starting“.

Additionally I did not accomplish to log the output. Maybe somebody can give me a hint on this. I tried to add a redirect to `command_args` but this did not work and a redirect of start-stop-daemon’s output is useless when run in background.

Answer (score 0):

This works (is the one shipped with gitea-openrc):

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run

supervisor=supervise-daemon
name=gitea
command="/usr/bin/gitea"
command_user="${GITEA_USER:-gitea}"
command_args="web --config '${GITEA_CONF:-/etc/gitea/app.ini}'"
supervise_daemon_args="--env GITEA_WORK_DIR='${GITEA_WORK_DIR:-/var/lib/gitea}' --chdir '${GITEA_WORK_DIR:-/var/lib/gitea}' --stdout '${GITEA_LOG_FILE:-/var/log/gitea/http.log}' --stderr '${GITEA_LOG_FILE:-/var/log/gitea/http.log}'"
pidfile="/run/gitea.pid"

depend() {
        use logger dns
        need net
        after firewall mysql postgresql
}
```

If you want to go ahead and use your script, please don't put the "&" at the end, and post the output of the logs.

.: Francesco